# creating a line chart using C3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to call a C3 line chart like it's done below:
http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html

Here's what I have in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/isogunro/m2cnpq7m/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#myChart',
data: {
  columns: [
    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
  ]
}
```

});

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have the js files added on your fiddle mate?

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you have c3 and d3 version 4. It seems [c3 is not yet compatible with d3 version 4](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1648) (you can see this by looking at your browser error console, finding TypeError c.scale is undefined and then doing a web search for why that occurs).

Replace the d3 version in your chart by d3 3.x and your code will work.

Comment: I will probably use a different charting tool b/c it takes too long for the chart load.